# How to partially close a trade in pinescript (tradingview)?

Tags: pine-script, trading

I'm struggling to figure out how to partially close open trades in pinescript in tradingview based on different conditions. I am trying to partially close trades with size `pos_size2` using `strategy.order` conditional upon the following:
-sell 50% conditional upon `long_stop2`
-sell remaining 50% conditional upon `long_stop1`

Any help would be appreciated.

```
// LONG
//my_margin = strategy.equity * margin_pct
//pos_size = (my_margin * leverage) / price
//pos_size2 = (my_margin * leverage2) / price
//symbol = security(syminfo.tickerid, resolution, close)
//percent = input(defval=50.0, title='Percentage of position to take profit.')
//size_trim = (pos_size2 / 2)

//Open Order
entry = 0

if trendhi_ema > trendlo_ema
    entry:=2
    strategy.entry(id='Long Signal', long=true, qty=pos_size2, when= window() and long_signal, comment = "2.5x Long")
else
    entry:=1
    strategy.entry(id='Long Signal', long=true, qty=pos_size, when= window() and long_signal, comment = "1.5x Long")

//Close Order

if trendhi_ema > trendlo_ema
    if entry == 2
        strategy.order(id='Long Signal', long=false, qty=size_trim, when= window() and long_stop2 and strategy.position_size > 0, comment = "close first 50% long")
        strategy.order(id='Long Signal', long=false, qty=size_trim, when= window() and long_stop1 and strategy.position_size > 0, comment = "close second 50% long")
    if entry == 1
        strategy.order(id='Long Signal', long=false, qty=pos_size, when= window() and long_stop2 and strategy.position_size > 0, comment = "close long")
else
    strategy.order(id='Long Signal', long=false, qty=pos_size, when= window() and long_stop2 and strategy.position_size > 0, comment = "close")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `id` parameter is important. Use same `id` when you want to MODIFY a `strategy.***` command parameters. Use different `id` if you want to specify different commands.

```
//Close Order

if trendhi_ema > trendlo_ema
    if entry == 2
        strategy.order(id='Long Signal 1', long=false, qty=size_trim, when= window() and long_stop2 and strategy.position_size > 0, comment = "close first 50% long")
        strategy.order(id='Long Signal 2', long=false, qty=size_trim, when= window() and long_stop1 and strategy.position_size > 0, comment = "close second 50% long")
    if entry == 1
        strategy.order(id='Long Signal 3', long=false, qty=pos_size, when= window() and long_stop2 and strategy.position_size > 0, comment = "close long")
else
    strategy.order(id='Long Signal 4', long=false, qty=pos_size, when= window() and long_stop2 and strategy.position_size > 0, comment = "close")
```